# Open a folder/directory on Android and iOS in Xamarin Forms in user's default file explorer

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I've found many articles about the web describing how to select a file, but there's scant information about just navigating to a folder path location using whatever file manager the user chooses to use.

My use case: my app creates a file and saves it to a location on the device. I then show on screen the file path that the file has been written to (so the user can find it). I've turned that path into a link so that the user can tap it - the idea being that it opens the default file manager at that location. There's no file to be selected and returned to my app; it's just a convenience feature.

Xamarin Essentials doesn't seem to cover this use case, and the other things I've tried are all tailored to returning a selected file to my app - which I'm not bothered about.

Any ideas?

Comment: As i know, the file picker could not open a specific folder. You could use specific ways for each platform to get the directories and then show it in the listview or some other layout to monitor a picker.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Thanks, I'll investigate further.

Comment: Have you try the way i provided?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Engineering the file listings for Android/iOS/Windows is looking like too much effort, so I've resorted to going down the route of just having the file manager open at its default location. It's not what I wanted, but ultimately it's the only way.